# How do I get my HTML button to delete the right list item from a SQLite database?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

I'm a beginner, so forgive any stupidity in advance. I'm using Flask (and by extension Jinja2) to create a simple web app -- one that basically lets you type a movie into a web form, which adds it to a SQLite database. I've gotten Flask to very nicely iterate through all the movies in the database and print them to the page upon load.

I want to include a "Delete" button next to each movie. Getting the button to appear is simple. But I'm not sure how to tie the button back to the function delete_movie() such that it will delete the correct movie associated with the button pressed.

Since there will be a button next to each movie, the form element must be dynamically named, I'm guessing. But if it's dynamically named, how do I pass the correct value back to the function? This is what I've got so far:

```
#movies.html
<div class=page>
    <h1>Movie List</h1>
    <ul class=movies>
    {% for movie in movies %}
        <li><h1>{{ movie.title }}</h1>
        <form action="{{ url_for('delete_movie') }}" method=post class=delete-movie><input type=submit value=Delete name=movie_to_delete"></form>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

#app.py
@app.route('/delete', methods=['POST'])
def delete_movie():
    g.db.execute('delete from movies where movie = ?', [request.form['movie_to_delete']])
    g.db.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('list_movies'))
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add a hidden input to every form with the element id/name that you want to delete as the value :)

eg.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('delete_movie') }}" method=post class=delete-movie>
  <input type=hidden value="{{ movie.name }}"name=movie_to_delete />
  <input type=submit />
</form>
```

Comment: Done. I'm a beginner at Stack Overflow as well as at coding ;)

Answer (score 6):

**IMO, the method in above answer is quite unnecessary.** You should pass the movie's name as URL variable:

```
{% for movie in movies %}
    <li><h1>{{ movie.title }}</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('delete_movie', movie_name=movie.name) }}" method=post>
        <input type=submit value=Delete">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

In view function, include the variable in URL rule (i.e. `/delete/<movie_name>`), then you can get the movie's name as a parameter:

```
@app.route('/delete/<movie_name>', methods=['POST'])
def delete_movie(movie_name):
    g.db.execute('delete from movies where movie = ?', [movie_name])
    ...
```

However, in this use case, people normally pass the id value of movie record instead of the name. Here is a minimal example from a [similar application](https://github.com/greyli/watchlist):

Template:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('delete_movie', movie_id=movie.id) }}">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

View:

```
@app.route('/movie/delete/<int:movie_id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_movie(movie_id):
    movie = Movie.query.get_or_404(movie_id)
    db.session.delete(movie)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Item deleted.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: What is the HTML if you want to use the method 'DELETE"? 

`@app.route('/delete/<movie_name>', methods=['DELETE'])`

the following HTML: 
`<form action="{{ url_for('delete_movie', movie_name=movie.name) }}" method=delete> ... </form>
does not work. Thanks

Comment: You can only use GET or POST in HTML. For other methods, you will need to use JavaScript to send the request.